# Overriding ASP Net Core settings with Environment Variables in a container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, appsettings

I need to overwrite **appsetings.json** **ProjectUsername** parameter with the environmental variable value in a container. I try to do it with the following command, but it doesn't overwrite ProjectUsername:

```
docker run \
-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging \
-e "ProjectUsername"="LimitedUser" \
project/selenium-tests
```

My IConfiguration code looks like this:

```
static string[] args = null;
    
    private static IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
                optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }).Build();
    
    protected IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationBaseUrl": "https://project.stag.net",
  "CareerCenterBaseUrl": "https://autoproject.stag.net/",
  "ClientLoginName": "autotestclient",
  "ProjectUsername": "CompleteUser"
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y

COPY . .

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
ENV ProjectUsername CompleteUser

RUN dotnet build
```

Just in case, I have appsettings.json for different environments. There are just application base URLs that are changed.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is entrypoint in your Dockerfile? Please, show its entire content. Final image should have ENV  directives in order to make it work. Why do you need apt-get update and install commands in your Dockerfile? Probably, that's the main problem - Dockerfile is not correct.

Comment: I don't have an Entrypoint, because I execute tests in TeamCity in a separate test. Basically executing command dotnet test. What are ENV directives?

Comment: `ENV` - you already have them declared aforementioned above. I don't get this argument about tests. I believe this is not the reason to write such sort of Dockerfiles, see [docs.docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). So, if you go this way, try to move line `RUN dotnet build` above ENV directives. But it still looks like a mess. You can declare `dotnet test` as your entrypoint command.

Comment: My presumption: if there is no entrypoint, it means that all of the commands are executed during the build of the Dockerfile. But final image is the one you create by executing specific command in docker run (ie `dotnet test`), and `ENV` are implicitly lost here. Try to rewrite your Dockerfile in a proper way.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. If I add ENTRYPOINT dotnet test, then my parameters get overwritten. Thanks a lot @Ryan